# Parse Cloud Code response is null after calling a function with callback

Tags: asynchronous, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a cloud code from which I call an external function.
The cloud code response is null but the console displays the response

my cloud code ;

```
Parse.Cloud.define("testccadd", async request => {
    try {
        var ccaddrequest = {  
            conversationId: '123456789',
            email: 'email@email.com', 
        };
        externalFunction (ccaddrequest, function (err, result) {
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        }) ;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error");  
    }
});
```

`console.log (result);` shows the values from the external function, but the `return result;` returns null

how can I get the external function response as response of my cloud code function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `externalFunction` uses a callback to return its result. That is an asynchronous event, meaning that it happens after your cloud functions has been processed.

The cloud function will execute `var ccaddrequest...` and then call `externalFunction` but it won't "wait" for `externalFunction` to call the callback function if it contains asynchronous commands.

So you need to wrap the `externalFunction` in a Promise (see [how to promisify callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22519785/6139038)) and then `await` the result of it.

Plus you need to return the result of the Promise, so in your code you need to add

```
Parse.Cloud.define("testccadd", async request => {
    try {
        var ccaddrequest = {  
            conversationId: '123456789',
            email: 'email@email.com', 
        };
        var result = await externalFunctionPromise(...);
        return result;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error");  
    }
});
```

Comment: great help. Very clean and clear explanation. Much appreciated.